# configuring sendmail for the first time

Tags: ubuntu, unix, email-server, sendmail

I am a newbie to all of this. I just installed sendmail however, I am getting the following error:

```
Apr 13 05:24:06 localhost sendmail[27071]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Apr 13 05:25:44 localhost sendmail[27074]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Apr 13 05:27:01 localhost sendmail[27076]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

What should I do?
I am guessing that it has to do with my /var/hosts setting. Please guide me through.

My hosts is:

127.0.0.1 localhost
50.56.81.42 admin.api.frapi

Answer (score 1):

While it may not directly answer your question, I would suggest you `apt-get install postfix` - this is just personal preference but I find it easy to configure & manage. Lots of people love sendmail, I'm just not one of them :)

Comment: I actually just uninstalled postfix and revert back to sendmail

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact answer for you, but I would recommend you to check out [this](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch21_:_Configuring_Linux_Mail_Servers#How_To_Configure_Linux_Sendmail_Clients) page for configuring Sendmail.